# How do I get a function to take a list of numbers to always be = to their negative index position

Tags: python, list

How do I get my function to take a list of numbers and make them always be equal to their negative index position for example, `[ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ] = 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5`

```
def writeallitems01(nums):
        nums=nums*-1
```

Comment: What you mean by *be equal*?

Comment: @HunterFarish Try not to copy and paste your comments, we're not machines. You're being asked a lot of questions because you're failing to be clear in your question. Edit the question, rather than carrying on a conversation in the comments. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the list in place:

```
def writeallitems01(nums):
    for idx in range(len(nums)) :
        nums[idx] = - idx
```

If you want to create a new list it's a bit easier:

```
def writeallitems01(nums):
    return [-x for x in range(len(nums)) ]
```

Comment: I've tried everyone response in this testing program and this is the error i get. the program injects a random list of numbers into my parameter ======================================================== You assigned: 2. You should have assigned 0. Check your logic and try again.

Comment: http://imgur.com/7aUYqWl

Comment: My first solution seems to give the required result for your teat case, as i understood the problem. Are you sure you are copying it correctly with indentation? Try running the code on your own in python console, rather than using external test cases, to see what goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
def writeallitems01(values):
    for i in range(len(values)):
        values[i] = -i
```

Comment: bare with me because im very very new to python but how would you right that in terms of a full function including nums as the parameter.

Comment: def nums55(nums):
 nums = [i*-1 for i in range(len(nums))]

Comment: https://codegrinder.cs.dixie.edu/#/assignment/3809

Comment: ^^^^^that link is what im working on

Comment: Edited my answer for this. Hope that helps.

Comment: I've tried everyone response in this testing program and this is the error i get. the program injects a random list of numbers into my parameter ======================================================== You assigned: 2. You should have assigned 0. Check your logic and try again.

Comment: his is the test question its like stupid easy i just cant figure it out

Comment: http://imgur.com/7aUYqWl

Comment: What is the problem with my answer? It should work.

Comment: this is the error that i get

Comment: http://imgur.com/dKBONxd

Comment: This problem doesnt seem to be from my function. I would request you to try again.

Comment: http://imgur.com/UwFvqgg

Comment: its not your function at all you did perfect its the dumb testing center

Comment: does this error make any sense to you?

Comment: your function works for me

Comment: Ohh. I am glad it helped.

Comment: does that last link i sent make any sense to you though? because even though your function works this testing center is wanting something else

Comment: I just changed my answer, which works well with your testing center code.

Answer (score 0):

updated according to traceback.

```
num_lst = [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ]

def writeallitems01(nums):
        return [-x for x in range(len(nums)) ]


print writeallitems01(num_lst)
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
```

Comment: I've tried everyone response in this testing program and this is the error i get. the program injects a random list of numbers into my parameter

========================================================
You assigned: 2. You should have assigned 0. Check your logic and try again.

Comment: please show you full error and input params

Comment: http://imgur.com/7aUYqWl

Comment: @hunterFarish updated

Comment: `-nums.index(x)` will give incorrect results if there are duplicate items in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to get the absolute value of each number before converting to its negative equivalent, so that it should not convert negative number with negation, which will make it positive in result.

```
def writeallitems01(input_list):
    for i in range(len(input_list)):
        input_list[i] = -abs(i)

values = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

writeallitems01(values)

print values
```

Results:

```
[0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]
```

Comment: I've tried everyone response in this testing program and this is the error i get. the program injects a random list of numbers into my parameter ======================================================== You assigned: 2. You should have assigned 0. Check your logic and try again.

Comment: its also looking for the index number to be the start of the answer so it should read 0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5

Comment: Can you include how exactly you are passing input list to your function, in your question.

Comment: http://imgur.com/7aUYqWl

Comment: this is the test question its like stupid easy i just cant figure it out

Comment: like i said i'm only a few hours into python coding

Comment: You have been asked to update the input list rather than returning new list and plus it is expecting `None` as return value from the function. Please view my updated answer.

Comment: Note that he wants the negative indices of the values rather than the negative values themselves

Comment: @ArthurVaiselbuh Thanks. My updated answer should work.